# Adapter not populating RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hey I have a current application that takes password information from user and stores it into a SQLiteDatabase. My problem is that I cannot get my RecyclerView to populate with this data. I can see that there are entries in the Database.

Code for my Adapter.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder> {
    protected ArrayList<PasswordResults> passwords;

    class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView id_tv;
        public TextView name_tv;
        public TextView website_tv;
        public TextView desc_tv;
        // public Button view_btn; (IGNORE)
        public TextView username_tv;
        public TextView password_tv;

        DataHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            id_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            name_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            website_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_website);
            desc_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);

            username_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
            password_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_password);
        }
    }

        DataAdapter(ArrayList<PasswordResults> inData){
            passwords = inData;
        }

        @Override
        public DataAdapter.DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type){
            View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.password_rows, parent, false);
            DataHolder passwordHolder = new DataHolder(v);
            return passwordHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolder holder, int position){
            PasswordResults passwordResults = passwords.get(position);

            // set values to text views.
            holder.id_tv.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
            String name = passwordResults.entryName;
            holder.name_tv.setText(name);
            String website = passwordResults.website;
            holder.website_tv.setText(website);
            String desc = passwordResults.description;
            holder.desc_tv.setText(desc);
            String username = passwordResults.username;
            holder.username_tv.setText(username);
            String password = passwordResults.password;
            holder.password_tv.setText(password);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return passwords.size();
        }
}
```

Here is my code for my database class

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // version, database name, and table name.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_Passwords";
    protected static final String TABLE_NAME = "passwords";

    public ArrayList<PasswordResults> passwords;

    // creating names for columns.
    public final static String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public final static String COLUMN_NAME = "entryName";
    public final static String COLUMN_WEBSITE = "website";
    public final static String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public final static String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    public final static String COLUMN_DESC = "description";

    // creating table string.
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists "+TABLE_NAME+" ("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_NAME +" VARCHAR(100), "
            + COLUMN_WEBSITE +" VARCHAR(100), "
            + COLUMN_USERNAME +" VARCHAR(100), "
            + COLUMN_PASSWORD +" VARCHAR(100), "
            + COLUMN_DESC +" TEXT)";

    // db helper
    public Database(Context c){
        super(c, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // create table when the app is loaded.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    // handle upgrades
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // drop and create new.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addPassword(String n, String w, String u, String p, String d) {
        // get database.
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            // add scores.
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME, n);
            values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, w);
            values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, u);
            values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, p);
            values.put(COLUMN_DESC, d);

            // insert will handle null values. closing.
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }

    public void removePassword(String id){
        // get database.
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        // delete database then close or print error.
        try {
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id="+id, null);
            db.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }

    public void updatePassword(String id, String n, String w, String u, String p, String d) {
        // get database.
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        //update database then close or print error.
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME, n);
            values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, w);
            values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, u);
            values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, p);
            values.put(COLUMN_DESC, d);
            db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id="+id, null);
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<PasswordResults> getPasswords() {
        // get database, password array, and select statement.
        passwords = new ArrayList<>();
        String refQuery = "Select "+COLUMN_NAME+", "+COLUMN_WEBSITE+", "+COLUMN_USERNAME+", "+COLUMN_PASSWORD+", "+COLUMN_DESC+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        // link to database
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(refQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
                passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(0);
                passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(1);
                passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(2);
                passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(3);
                passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(4);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return passwords;
    }

    public ArrayList<PasswordResults> getSelectedPassword(String id) {
        // get database, password array, and select statement.
        passwords = new ArrayList<>();
        String refQuery = "Select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = "+id;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        // link to database
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(refQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
                passwordResults.id = cursor.getInt(0);
                passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(1);
                passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(2);
                passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(3);
                passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(4);
                passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(5);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return passwords;
    }

}
```

Here is my class that holds the results

```
public class PasswordResults {
    public int id;
    public String entryName;
    public String website;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String description;
}
```

Comment: please show how you pass data to DataAdapter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both methods getPasswords() and getSelectedPasswords() you are creating an empty ArrayList on these lines:

```
passwords = new ArrayList<>();
```

but you then return passwords without ever adding the passwordResults into it. In getSelectedPasswords(), the code below:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
            passwordResults.id = cursor.getInt(0);
            passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(1);
            passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(2);
            passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(3);
            passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(4);
            passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(5);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return passwords;
```

should be changed to:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
            passwordResults.id = cursor.getInt(0);
            passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(1);
            passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(2);
            passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(3);
            passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(4);
            passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(5);
            passwords.add(passwordResults); //This line is missing!
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return passwords;
```

the same must also be added to the getPasswords() method.

Comment: No worries, if you could upvote the answer as well that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment but this might help.
Once you populate your ArrayList,did you call ?

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If not, you must do it. If yes, make sure your recycler view is surely not being populated with the data and theres not an issue with your layout xml file. Because often if your layout file for the recyclerView is not designed correctly,you wont be able to visibly see it even if the recyclerView and it's adapter is doing it's work perfectly fine from the java code.